# Show selected index of datagridview on another form using pre-defined textboxes?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

First time posting and is a beginner in vb.net data-basing.

I've got a datagridview on form1 which gets populated through a datasource. (access database from file). On form1 i have the datagridview to show all of my "projects and details. I can either double click a cell or click a button to go to the Edit Projects form. On the Edit Projects form i have placed the pre-defined details from the datasource.(textboxes, checkboxes etc. )

Now my problem is, when i go to the Edit Projects form, it does not pull through the selected row's details, but the default first row details.

On form load the adaptor gets filled like this.

```
Me.ProjectsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectsXDataSet.Projects)
```

When i go to Edit Form

```
Public Sub Editproject()
    'Disable form 1 to lock interface while editing a project
    '
    Me.Enabled = False
    Form2.Show()

End Sub

Public Sub CellDoubleClick()
    Form2.TextBox1.Text = ""
    Form2.TextBox2.Text = ""
    Form2.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    Dim filenme As String = Form2.ProjectTextBox.Text & ".txt"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filenme) = True Then
        Form2.TextBox2.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Form2.ProjectTextBox.Text & ".txt")
        Dim pathfolder As String = Form2.TextBox2.Text
        Dim stringpath As String = pathfolder & "\" '

        Form2.DataGridView1.DataSource = Fileinfo_To_DataTable(pathfolder)
    Else
        '  MsgBox("Please add a workfolder")
    End If

    Try
        Dim project As String = Form2.ProjectTextBox.Text
        Dim filenme2 As String = project & " notes.txt"
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filenme2)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

I've tried playing around with updating the tableadaptor but i can not figure anything out.

Launch code added:

```
Private Sub EditProjectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditProjectToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Editproject()
    CellDoubleClick()
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
    Editproject()
    CellDoubleClick()
End Sub
```

See image....I double click the selected row im the datagridvew, which opens the editing form(form2). but with the linked textboxes it shows row 1(0)'s values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r6Co.jpg)

Comment: Where is `Form2` instantiated?

Comment: When i doublick on a cell

Comment: I do not see this in the posted code… can you show where this is done?

Comment: Launch code added to my question

Comment: I have added an image to show the problem

Comment: What does the form2 constructor look like?

Comment: not sure what you mean?  I'm new to vb.net and windows forms

Comment: Me.ProjectsBindingSource.DataSource = Form1.ProjectsXDataSet fixed the problem. It was Me.ProjectsBindingSource.DataSource = me.ProjectsXDataSet on form2.

Comment: Great! If you got it working, then it looks like you are good to go.